# Run-time error '1004' : PasteSpecial method of Range class failed when attempting to copy a row with matching criteria from one table to another

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a workbook that stores quite a bit of data. I am trying to import a weekly report, paste it in a table, loop through the imported information and if a row does not match the issue key in a second table, the row needs to be copied and pasted into the second table.

Everything works until it gets to the Paste part of the code. It seems that the selection does not stay copied? I have tried several troubleshooting methods but none have worked.

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim DAHelpPulse As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse & Import Jira Pulse Check", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
    
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        
        Set DAHelpPulse = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        DAHelpPulse.Sheets(1).Range("A2", Range("M2").End(xlDown)).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Visible = True
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        DAHelpPulse.Close False
        SearchandExtract
        
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
End Sub

Sub SearchandExtract()

    Dim datasheet As Worksheet
    Dim ticketsheet As Worksheet
    Dim homesheet As Worksheet
    Dim issuekey As String
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Range
    Dim TicketReviewTable As ListObject
    
    Set datasheet = Sheet9
    Set ticketsheet = Sheet2
    Set homesheet = Sheet6
    issuekey = ticketsheet.Range("B2").Value
    
    datasheet.Select
    finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To finalrow
    
        If Cells(i, 2) <> issuekey Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(1, 13)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheet2.ListObjects("TicketReview").ListRows.Add
        Set TicketReviewTable = Sheet2.ListObjects("TicketReview")
        Set LastRow = TicketReviewTable.ListRows(TicketReviewTable.ListRows.Count).Range
        With LastRow
        LastRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
        datasheet.Select

        End If
    
    Next i
    
    homesheet.Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("M2").End(xlDown)` is not qualified with a sheet, so it is assuming `ActiveSheet` which is not the same as  `DAHelpPulse.Sheets(1)`

Comment: You have lots of other Range references too that are not qualified, so you are just asking for trouble.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am not experienced at all - this has been pieced together from internet searches and recording/tweaking macros. Luckily, the importing of data from Get_Data_From_File has worked with no issues so far. I am having trouble copying rows out of the data and pasting it in a different table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you really need to split this up into two subs - that just means you end up re-defining items already assigned in the first step.

Untested:

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant, rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
    Dim DAHelpPulse As Workbook, tbl As ListObject, issuekey, rw As Range
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse & Import Jira Pulse Check", _
                 FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
    
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        Set DAHelpPulse = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        With DAHelpPulse.Sheets(1)
            Set rngCopy = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("M2").End(xlDown))
        End With
            
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")
            .Visible = True
            Set rngPaste = .Range("A2").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Columns.Count)
        End With
        rngPaste.Value = rngCopy.Value
        DAHelpPulse.Close False 'no save
        
        Set tbl = Sheet2.ListObjects("TicketReview")
        issuekey = Sheet2.Range("B2").Value
        
        For Each rw In rngPaste.Rows
            If rw.Cells(2) <> issuekey Then
                tbl.ListRows.Add.Range.Value = rw.Value
            End If
        Next rw
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```